# How do you safely clear an object from memory (with attributes) which was created using the new keyword?

Tags: c++, class, new-operator, delete-operator

As far as I know on this topic, every "new" call needs a corresponding "delete" call to that object. So is this really correct?:

```
using namespace std;

class Box {
   public:
      double length;
      char letters_in_box[80];
};

int main() {
   Box *b = new Box;
   b->length = 2.0;
   b->letters_in_box = "Hello world";

   //Some code with b

   delete b;

   return 0;
}
```

Is the memory associated with the "length" double and "letters_in_box" array cleared with this?

Comment: I guess you mean "from another process" and then the answer is operating system specific. Please provide some [mre] in your question, and be aware of the [C++ rule of five](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-five.html).  You probably want to define a C++ destructor

Comment: There is no guarantee and I think you should not ask yourself this question.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I don't think `b->letters_in_box = "Hello world";` will compile, considering that `letters_in_box` is an array.

Comment: Assuming that all this happens in the same function or block, then you might not want to use dynamic storage duration at all. And instead just use `auto b = Box();`.

Comment: And also really really read this : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii
Couple resource managment (e.g. memory allocation) to the lifecycle of objects.
Constructor/Destructor pairs in C++ are the best friends you have.

Comment: I agree that one should know about the rule of zero/three/five. For `Box` no destructor is needed (or any additional work is need). But in case that `Box *b` is a member of another class (and that raw pointer is an owning pointer) the rule of zero/three/five is really important. @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: You should also use `std::string`. Given that your simple code has so many issues, I highly recommand you to **read some books on C++**. C++ is not a good language for improvisation as there are so many possible pitfalls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. When you delete `b` it deletes also `letters_in_box` array.

But, for your `b->letters_in_box = "Hello world";` you will get a compile error: "error C3863: array type 'char [80]' is not assignable"

```
#include <memory> // For 'memcpy_s' (since C11)

class Box
{
public:
    double length;
    char letters_in_box[80];
};

int main()
{
    Box* b = new Box;

    b->length = 2.0;
    // b->letters_in_box = "Hello world"; ** Compile Error C3863: array type 'char [80]' is not assignable **
    memcpy_s(b->letters_in_box, sizeof(b->letters_in_box), "Hello world", sizeof("Hello world"));

    // Some code with b

    delete b;
}
```

**MODERN C++**

A better practice than `new` is **smart pointers**, than for example you don't have to bother with delete in case of exception and at all:

```
#include <memory> // For 'std::unique_ptr' and for 'memcpy_s'

class Box
{
public:
    double length;
    char letters_in_box[80];
};

constexpr char my_text[] = "Hello world"; 

int main()
{
    auto b = std::make_unique<Box>(); // No need to delete

    b->length = 2.0;
    memcpy_s(b->letters_in_box, sizeof(b->letters_in_box), my_text, sizeof(my_text));

    // Some code with b
}
```

Also, (instead of C array) I prefer to use **C++ array**:

```
#include <array>  // For 'std::array'
#include <memory> // For 'std::unique_ptr' and for 'memcpy_s' 

class Box
{
public:
    double length;
    std::array<char, 80> letters_in_box;
};
   
constexpr char my_text[] = "Hello world";

int main()
{
    auto b = std::make_unique<Box>(); // No need to delete

    b->length = 2.0;
    memcpy_s(&b->letters_in_box, b->letters_in_box.size(), my_text, sizeof(my_text));

    //Some code with b
}
```

--

**One last comment:** Without a constraint to use `char[]`, I would use `std::string` instead:

```
#include <string> // For 'std::string'
#include <memory> // For 'std::unique_ptr' 

class Box
{
public:
    double length;
    std::string letters_in_box;
};

int main()
{
    auto b = std::make_unique<Box>(); // No need to delete

    b->length = 2.0;
    b->letters_in_box = "Hello world";

    //Some code with b
}
```

Comment: The `memcpy` has undefined behavior, because it is accessing char well past the end of the C-string literal.

Comment: @Eljay Thank you for the comment. I switched to memcpy_s.

Answer (score 1):

In modern C++ it is highly recommended **not** to use new and delete for the reason that Karen has alluded to above, if an exception occurs for whatever reason during the program, and your exception handling causes a branch that does not return back to run delete, then this causes a memory leak.

Instead I would look into using smart pointers (https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) for creating new pointers to objects used, as these will allow for the de-allocation of memory once they go out of scope (unique pointers) (i.e. an exception branch followed by not returning to the same scope), or once their number of 'references' expires (shared pointers).

With respect to the explicit code you have written, yes once that class is deleted the "length" double and "letters_in_box" array will be deleted, however it is important to note that if you have explicitly used malloc/calloc/etc for allocating memory, then a class destructor should be used in order to free this memory.

Edit: Also would strongly recommend reading RAII (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) as it is really is the foundation of modern, safe C++.

Answer (score 0):

> So is this really correct?

Yes, it is correct. However, you have to make sure that it is not thrown an exception before deleting the `b`.

For example:

```
Box *b = new Box;
b->length = 2.0;
b->letters_in_box = "Hello world";

throw 5; //this is not usually done.

delete b;
```

In this example, if the exception is not handled before calling `delete`, a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) will occur.

Comment: So how do you ensure it is deleted even if an exception occurs?

Comment: @CoderAlpha, you have to handle the exception before calling `delete`.

Comment: @CoderAlpha the best thing is to avoid `new` and `delete` at all. In modern c++ you rarely need `new` and `delete`. If you create an object that should only exist locally in a function or a block just write `Box b = Box();`. If you need to transfer ownership you could go with `unique_ptr`, if `unique_ptr` does not fit your needs you `shared_ptr`.

Comment: So `Box b = Box();` wont need any deletion as it is on the stack right? But what if we need more memory than the stack size?

Comment: @CoderAlpha Yes. If the amount of data enclosed by `Box` could exceed the stack, you could use `unique_ptr` (`std::unique_ptr<Box> b = std::make_unique<Box>();`). Or change one (or more) of the members of `Box` to something different like a `std::vector`. But what solution to choose depends on the actual use-case.